# Steam not working on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, steam

Steam isn't working - I've tried relaunching and reinstalling, but it doesn't help. Is there a simple solution or not? The log is here: https://gist.github.com/homelyseven250/af747f3ed9275e03d35e267637d08c0f

Comment: One problem. Steam cannot find your python3-apt package, which has been included in every Ubuntu Desktop install for many years. We don't know how you managed to uninstall it, or if you are using some based-on-Ubuntu variant that simply doesn't include it.

Comment: `python3-apt is already the newest version (1.6.5ubuntu0.3).`
Is what I got when I tried to install it